# Find And Replace in a Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase

Is there a way or a tool to mimic "find and replace" functionality in a Geodatabase (File, Persoanl, Enterprise). For example I need to remove a string from all FeaturClass names.

for example in the following cases, I need to remove "Pattern_":

- Pattern_Road1
- Pattern_Parcel
- Pattern_Buildings

Comment: without using arcpy (python)?

Comment: The goal of this question is not python (or model builder), however a python solution is honored. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Python solution:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Data.gdb" #change to where your data is stored

fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Pattern_*")

for fc in fc_list:
    new_name = fc.split("_")[-1]
    arcpy.Rename_management(fc, new_name)
```

This actually alters the original name of each input feature class. It does not export a copy with the new name. So, you may want to create a backup of your data before you run it.

---

As suggested by @mr.adam, you could use the following code to see what the name changes will be before you actually run the Rename tool:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Data.gdb" #change to where your data is stored

output = open("C:\\Rename_results.txt", "w") #change to where you want text file exported

fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Pattern_*")

for fc in fc_list:
    new_name = fc.split("_")[-1]

    output.write("{0} ---> {1}\n".format(fc, new_name))

output.close()
```

The above code writes the name changes to a text file, so you can review them.

```
Pattern_Road1 ---> Road1
Pattern_Parcel ---> Parcel
Pattern_Buildings ---> Buildings
```

Comment: I'd also recommend a dry-run where you comment out the `arcpy.Rename...` line and just print `new_name`, to do a visual inspection before actually running the process.

Comment: @mr.adam yeah, that'd be a good idea. I added some additional code to write the name changes to a text file.

Comment: Thanks @ian . What about other dataset types (tables, rasters,..)? does this code rename them too?

Comment: @FaridCher There are similar functions for those, ListRasters() and ListTables(), you can see a list of them at the top of this page: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//018v00000018000000

Comment: That's for sure. With a little bit of effort your solution can become a useful geoprocessing tool for the "Find and Replace" functionaly. Thanks anyway